# Why folder or file name in Windows cannot end with space?

Tags: windows, ntfs, path, filenames

I learned something new today. When I tried create new folder "folder " (no quotes) in Visual Studio I got error:

> Directory names cannot contain any of the following characters:
>
> :  *  ?  |  "  <  >

But my folder name **doesn't have any of those characters**. So I tried creating this folder in Windows explorer and it strips space from end and creates folder "folder" instead of "folder ". Same does `md` command and same goes for file names. Why folder or file name in Windows cannot end with space?

I tried this on NTFS partition (Windows 8.1).

Comment: If you're just asking theoretically, very well. If not, why would you want to end a filename with a space?

Comment: I'm asking theoretically.

Comment: What does Visual Studio have to do with creating folders?

Answer (score 7):

From Microsoft [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) article:

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Comment: If anyone knows why "Windows shell and user interface does not support such names" that would be even better answer.

Comment: @Pol - "Why" would be outside of the purview of this website.

Comment: @Ramhound - Why = technical or UI **reasons** = scope of this website, I guess. If not, what other Stack Exchange site would suit better? I'm assuming this wasn't irony. Cheers.

Comment: @Pol - Because "why" is a broad question.  "Why" can only be answered by Microsoft which won't happen.  The technical reasons are public hence this answer.  Besides it **can** actually be used....its just not supported by Windows Explorer or the shell.  **If both were replaced you could**

Comment: @Ramhound - CreateFileA from kernel32.dll (not a shell part) doesn't allow creating (opening) two files whose name is different only by space at the end. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the characters you mentioned there is also

> \ /

Some of these characters are wildcard characters, and the other used in the path for the file or directory.
So, you cant use any of them in the folder or file name.